# How to auto count in excel

Tags: excel, count

sub()

Hi,

I want to summarize the unit's status in the below table.
Currently i using manually count.
How can i make it auto? That mean if i change the 'status' ,the table below will auto change.
Please see my screenshot.

Is it need to use excel macro to make it, I have no idea.
Please help me on this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you try `COUNTIF()`?

Comment: I will recommend using a Pivot Table especially if the size of data and status elements also keep changing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIF()` function then `SUM()`.

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,D2)
```

For total

```
=SUM(E2:E4)
```

[image]

Comment: @Astatine Then please accept the answer (tick mark it).